# Pagination algorithm working incorrectly

Tags: javascript, algorithm, pagination

I've got a fairly simple pagination algorithm here but it's not working the way I'd like it to.

Currently it's displaying like this

```
1 2 3 ... 33 34 35 [36] 37 38 ... 47 48 49 50
```

When it should be displaying like this

```
1 2 3 ... 33 34 35 [36] 37 38 39 ... 48 49 50
```

Here's my code, I wrote it very quickly. It also seems to continuously run (The loop doesn't stop) but I've no idea why.

```
$(function(){
            var pages = 50;                 //Total number of pages
            var current = 36;               //The current page we are on
            var before = 3;                 //Number of links to display before current
            var after = 3;                  //Same as above but after
            var start = (current - before); //The number of the first link
            var end = (current + after);    //Number of the end link

            for(var i = 1; i <= pages; i++){
                if(i == (before + 1)){
                    i = start;
                    document.write('...');
                }
                else if(i == (current + after)){
                    i = (pages - after);
                    document.write('...');
                }
                if(i == current){
                    document.write(' ['+i+'] ');
                }
                else{
                    document.write(' '+i+' ');
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: +1 since i cant see why this should be -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `current + after` is 39 (36 + 3) here, so no wonder it displays "..." instead of 39, increase "after" by 1 to fix this
2. after looking at the code for several minutes, I don't have a clue why it should run forever :) Have you tried writing "i" to the console to check what values it takes and why it never reaches its "final value"?

Answer (score 2):

Please fix `after` to `after + 1` in 2 places in all places in your loop where you use it.

Also, I am not sure your code will work correctly for edge cases (e.g. where current == 2) - you may want to test that

Comment: Actually, he can't just change the variable, since `(pages - (after + 1)) == 46`. The second option is better, since it would produce `(pages - after + 1) == 48`, the correct code in the second instance.

Answer (score 2):

If `(current + after) > (pages - after)` and `(current + after) < pages` then this code will run forever because of:

```
else if(i == (current + after)){
    i = (pages - after);
    document.write('...');
}
```

Each time `i` reaches `current + after`, it will be reduced to `pages - after` and that cycle will continue indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason why arrays used zero-based indexing in most languages: the math is just simpler. In your case, since you obviously *can't* use zero-based indexing, you'll just have to fix the off-by-one errors:

```
else if(i == (current + after + 1)){
    i = (pages - after + 1);
    document.write('...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following algorithm gives 5 pages around the current page

Example:
- [X] is the current page
- In this case the total pages are 20

```
<[1] 2 3 4 5>   
<1 [2] 3 4 5>  
<1 2 [3] 4 5>        
<2 3 [4] 5 6>  
...  numbers in between ...  
<15 16 [17] 18 19>  
<16 17 [18] 19 20>  
<16 17 18 [19] 20>   
<16 17 18 19 [20]>
```

Or in case total pages are less than 5, say 3...
The results look like

```
<[1] 2 3>
```

And so on.

```
function (page, totalPages) {
    var leftBoundry = Math.max(1, page - 2)
    var rightBoundry = Math.min(totalPages, page + 2)
    var arr = []
    var emptyRight = 2 - (rightBoundry - page)
    var emptyLeft = 2 - (page - leftBoundry)

    leftBoundry = Math.max(1, leftBoundry - emptyRight)
    rightBoundry = Math.min(totalPages, rightBoundry + emptyLeft)

    for (var i = leftBoundry; i <= rightBoundry; i++) {
        arr.push(i)
    }

    return arr;
}
```

.